# “recce” — the reck which a reckless is lacking

Tags: etymology, archaicisms

While thinking about good antonyms for *reckless*, I noticed there’s no *reckful* nor any *reck* in English, for that matter. So, what would that *reck* be?

[Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=reckless) offers the following scrap:

> *rece, recce* “care, heed” from *reccan* “to care”

A very pretty word, and I’d love to learn more about it. When did it die out? Did it differ subtly from *care* as *careless* differs from *reckless*, with special connotations? How was it pronounced? Did it function just like *care* or did it have its own set of prepositions for use in various contexts?

Could it be used in role of “tender care”, related to love? *“I recce for thee”*?

Comment: “Only the Teleri beyond the mountains still sang upon the shores of the sea; for they **recked** little of seasons  or times, and gave no thought to the cares of the Rulers of Arda, or the shadow that had fallen on Valinor, for it had not touched them, as yet.” ―J.R.R. Tolkien, *The Silmarillion*

Comment: The other *recce*: a reconnaissance mission.

Comment: Yes, Hugo. That is used in a military context.

Comment: A question for these who vote to close this as general reference, can you point me to *which* general reference resource contains the answers to my questions (these asked below the quote), specifically about the old form, "recce", not modern "reck"?

Comment: @tchrist though any citation from Tolkien can be considered a bad data-point as far as usage goes. Of the top of my head, *wrack* (outside of the cranberry collocation "wrack and ruin), *wicca* (before Gardner's writings on the modern form of witchcraft with that spelling, but modern pronunciation), *lampads* (anywhere except some translations of Revelations). He deliberately used obscure or obsolete words, precisely because they're no longer used.

Comment: @JonHanna For certain nouns he rescued from OE or ME, sure: *Dwimordene, dwimmerlaik, dwimmer-crafty, mathom, Thain,*, and perhaps things like *weapontake, Westmarch, and muster*. He did this quite deliberately, to let the older names bring to mind the older things.  However, when it came to verbs and function words, I do not think so. Only in some of his very earliest writings would he deliberately adopt an archaic style, and use such things as *an* to mean *if*.  He was ever careful in his word choices. Consider his response to the criticism that he uses *eyot*: what else would you call it?

Comment: @tchrist, The Silmarillion while worked on since, did come from some of his earliest work. It was also aiming to seem archaic from the perspective of LotR, so the defense of *eyot* wouldn't apply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is *reck* in English, though perhaps not in common usage these days.

The [Oxford English Dictionary](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/159578) has:

> From its earliest appearance in English, the verb is almost exclusively employed in negative or interrogative clauses. In the former the simple negative may be replaced by nought, nothing, little, not much, etc.; in the latter, the pronoun what is most usual. Now chiefly arch. and literary.
>
> 1. intr. With of. In Old and early Middle English also with genitive.
>
> a. To take care or thought for or notice of something, along with inclination, desire, or favour towards it, interest in it, etc.; to think (much, etc.) of.
>
> b. To take notice of or be concerned about something, so as to be alarmed or troubled by it, or so as to modify one's behaviour or purposes on account of it.

The latter definition would seem to be where *reckon* stems from.

Comment: Elendil should know the Silmarillion. :)

Answer (score 1):

***[reck](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%20reck)***

> *verb* /rek/ 
>   recked, past participle; recked, past tense; recking, present participle; recks, 3rd person singular present
>   Pay heed to something
>           - ye reck not of lands or goods
>           - little recking where she was wandering
>           - he recks not Syria, recks not Britain
>   It is of importance
>           - what recks it?
>   **Synonyms**
>   *verb*: mind, care, heed

Also,
http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/reck
Alternative forms
    reak (*obsolete*)
Derived terms
    reckful
    reckless

http://oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/reck

Comment: Someone was itching to down vote again.